# php mail function work well in windows but not in linux server

Tags: php, linux, email

**I have use mail function like this work well in windows but not in linux server.what's wrong with my code..anyone can give some ideas/better one solution for this.I am also have refer some SMTP option but that all throw error while run time.**

```
  <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$email_recipient = "staff@inpws.com";
$email_subject="hi";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@oktakes.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@oktakes.com";

$email_result = mail($email_recipient, $email_subject, "hiuu", $headers);
if ($email_result){ echo "Email has been sent!"; }
else{ echo "Email has failed!"; }
?>
```

Comment: Have you installed a Mail Transfer Agent such as sendmail? What do your logs say, what is the value of $email_result. What's in your mail logs?

Comment: no error.just show mail sent successfully msg

Comment: Okay, and the rest of what I wrote?

Comment: i have edit and update my mail..

Answer (score 0):

`$email_header` doesn't exist.

```
$email_result = mail($email_recipient, $email_subject, $email_contents, $headers);
```

And in the 3rd line of `$headers` variable should be `\r\n` instrad of `\n`.

```
$headers .= "From: info@oktakes.com\r\n";
```

Comment: i have check it directly, so that i mention like this, and also have change to your idea, it's just seems like that.but mail not delivered..

Comment: i have edit and update my mail..

Answer (score 0):

are you try to enable error to see the error as

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

and you have a syntax error at this line

```
$email_contents .= "<br><b>Sender: " . hi uu;
```

should be

```
$email_contents .= "<br><b>Sender: " . "hi uu";
```

try that and see what is the error and replace `$email_header` with `$headers`

```
$email_result = mail($email_recipient, $email_subject, $email_contents, $email_header);
```

Comment: i have change and ran it, but no error and mail not delivered..actually my hosting server is linux.i have read related to that..i think it may be some think issue related to web hosting / server..bro.. else..

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_result = mail($email_recipient, $email_subject, $email_contents, $headers);
```